# SI_TKILL si_code on ARM for division with zero

Tags: linux, arm, signals, buildroot

Currently, I am writing a signal handler for ARM to provide as much debug information as I can. For testing purposes, I cause different calamities. The signal I receive is`SIGFPE`, as expected, but the *si_code* differs from what I expected. I am wondering, why the *si_code* for integer division with zero is set to `SI_TKILL` instead of `FPE_INTDIV` or any other `SIGFPE` si_code on ARM.

The following function is used to cause the error:

```
int divide_by_zero()
{
   int c = 1;
   int b = 0;
   return c / b;
}
```

Is this the default behavior? Are the *si_codes* on ARM reduced?

I use the arm-linux-gcc compiler for the target which is provided by Buildroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [POSIX](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), division by zero yields an undefined result, and on some architectures, it will generate a SIGFPE signal.

---

On the other hand, the *[Run-time ABI for the ARM Architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0043d/IHI0043D_rtabi.pdf)*, 4.3.2 Division by zero:

> If an integer or long long division helper function is called upon to divide by 0, it should return as quotient the value returned by a call to __aeabi_idiv0 or __aeabi_ldiv0, respectively. A *divmod helper should return as remainder either 0 or the original numerator.
>
> (Aside: Ideally, a *divmod function should return {infinity, 0} or {0, numerator}, where infinity is an approximation. End aside).
>   The *div0 functions:
>
>  Return the value passed to them as a parameter.
>
>  Or, return a fixed value defined by the execution environment (such as 0).
>
>  *Or, raise a signal (often SIGFPE) or throw an exception, and do not return.*

So implicity, both are indicating that a signal or exception instead of `FPE_INTDIV` when an integer zero division is performed is possible and valid.

Comment: So I get the expected behavior as described in POSIX and the Run-time ABI for the ARM Architecture. But I thought that the _si_codes_  like `FPE_INTDIV` should provide more information about the caught signal, in this case, `SIGFPE`.

Comment: Is there some way of determining if si_codes will be provided on my ARM architecture when they are not mandatory?

Comment: I don't know, but you can trap and deal with integer division by zero: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0097a/armcc_cjaddjea.htm